# Retrieve index of a List<> item based in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

It is a pretty simple question, I have a list of an object that has a Field Named "ID".

How can I retrieve the Index of an object in the list if I know the ID?

Example:

```
CUSTOM_OBJECTS test = new CUSTOM_OBJECTS{ID=50};
List<CUSTOM_OBJECTS> List = new List<CUSTOM_OBJECTS>();
List.Add(test);
```

I would like to retrieve the index of the object with ID = 50 in the list, which would be 0 in this example.

Comment: You have your answer below, but you should **really** be thinking about your coding standards. The all-upper-case name of the class, and capital letter of your list object will make your code unpleasant to read for most other developers. Going off to wash my eyes now!

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience :-) Classes have to be in CamelCase?

Comment: They don't have to be in CamelCase, it's just that using only capital letters makes code hard to read (and also looks very sql-style :) )

Comment: @Orf - Normally classes, properties, events and the like are CamelCase, fields, local variables, parameters and so on are pascalCase. You are of course free to choose this as you like, but that will be most "compatible" with your fellow C# developers :)

Comment: @Øyvind - You have it mixed up, PascalCase is the first letter in the identifier and the first letter of each subsequent word are uppercase. camelCase is lowercase first letter and uppercase for each subsequent word.

Comment: @Phill - That is of course correct. I got put of by the previous comment writing it as CamelCase :) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var index = List.FindIndex(x=>x.ID==50);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure FindIndex only exists on the List<T> class, so it will not work on other IEnumerables. Just in case anyone gets confused at some point.

Comment: @Glenn: Yes, `FindIndex()` it's a regular `List<T>` method, not a LINQ's one ;)

Comment: @tchrikch - Didn't know about `FindIndex` myself, so I appreciated this answer. Congrats on your first silver badge that you will recieve as soon as Orf accept this answer :)

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen Thanks, I know it's not exactly a LINQ method yet still if you work on generic List<T> objects it's great

Answer (score -3):

```
CUSTOM_OBJECT singleObject = list.Single(co => co.ID == 50)
```

You can also use the methods SingleOrDefault, First, or FirstOrDefault.

Comment: -1 He says he wants the index of the object with that ID, not the object itself.